# How to get rid of the /webroot/page/home in the url of my website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I've made a website and want to put it online now. It's already on a domain but there's a problem. The URL's are still weird and I want to fix it but don't know how.

How it is: `example.com/webroot/page/home` -  `example.com/webroot/page/membersInfo/infoBulletin/`

How it should be : `example.com`           -  `example.com/membersinfo/infobulletin`

I want to get rid of `/webroot/page/`

Thanks a lot,

Anona

I use : Twig, Html, Bootstrap, JS, JQ, CSS, PHP, JSON

Comment: naruto how do you do that?? , in the edit

Comment: Put the website at the root of the web server, not in a sub-folder.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess in your webroot? Looks like .htaccess isnt allowed. Did it work on your local PC? Is your local PC happen to work on windows while your live-system is running linux? In this case I assume you forgot to enable AllowOverride for your directory.

Comment: David i want the structure to stay the same and steini, local works but also had the webroot/page/ and I don't have Linux I work on windows

Comment: And your server is windows aswell?

Comment: and how do I enable AllowOveride

Comment: I don't know for sure but I work in this company as intern but i have DirectAdmin

Comment: Your web-folder does contain a .htaccess correct? Then you need one posibility to enable OverrideAll, usually this works modifying your /etc/apache2/sites-available/your-site.conf while adding  
<Directory "/var/www/path">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory> to the file. However this requires direct access to the server or there must be some option in your admin interface.

Comment: my htacces is completely empty except for Options -Indexes

Comment: @David, that WOULD work, but I wouldn't recommend it  because it discourages organization, which in turn encourages bad programming IMO.

Comment: @Jakar: If there are more sites to be organized, sure.  The OP makes no mention of that.  So I suppose it's just as fair for you to assume the existence of other sites as it is for me to assume otherwise.  But having a single site at the server root wouldn't exactly be "bad programming".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to move your site folders to be up two directories, but I would discourage that. If you can keep your site files organized (i.e. use subdirectories), your life will be easier.

I think something like this in your `.htaccess` will work. If not, let me know and I'll play with it:

```
#if rewrite engine isn't already on
RewriteEngine On 

#in case you only want to rewrite the path for say, mysite.com, then use this RewriteCond as well
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} mysite.com
#rewrite the request at the root to have /webroot/page in front of it
RewriteRule (.+) /webroot/page$1 [L]
```